# Mirrored Code Igniter section of website is motionless offline

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I really hope someone can help me here - this is my first piece of work in this area and I have hit upon an issue I cannot fix and I starting to pull my hair out looking for an answer.

#### Overview

The plan was to mirror an existing functionional website offline for testing new site designs.

Online the site appears to be hosted on a standard shared host. There is an FTP login and a control panel which gives access to the typical hosting, database and mailbox setup.

Offline I am running RHEL 6.2 (Scientific Linux) with freshly installed Apache, mysql and PHP. I have the site content running as a virtual host on a dummy local domain and have copied the contents of the mysql database locally.

Versions - Apache 2.2.15 (Scientific Linux) PHP 5.3.3 Mysql 5.1.61

At a basic level my offline mirror works. Apache is serving up the HTML/CSS and images. The PHP files for the main content are pulling information out of the database and displaying it in the browser visible website.

#### The problem...

...is that the back-end administration section of the website appears to be in suspended animation - at the login panel stage it just sits there, unresponsive, when credentials are entered.

I had been hoping that I could just change the MD5 encrypted password stored in the database and then get the admin section up and running offline.

There is also a very slight visual difference between the online and offline versions of the login page.

Online [https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLBsS.jpg]
Offline [https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QXlc.jpg]

This admin section has been coded in PHP using CodeIgniter as the framework.

#### Here are my notes so far from attempting to fix this....

**Mod_rewrite seems to be required by CodeIgniter.**

I have confirmed this module is loaded by my local Apache (the module is listed to load in httpd.conf) and I have tested that it is working.

The strange thing is that the method used to test relies on settings in a .htaccess file, while on the live site the .htaccess file is an empty file and I cannot find any other file on the FTP or switch via the admin panel that sets up mod_rewrite.

If mod_rewrite is required for CodeIgniter then it is a mystery how it is setup on the online server. (It is worth me saying that it is /possible/ that there is a httpd.conf config for this on the server itself as the hosting company and original web design firm have very similiar names so may be one and the same.)

**$config['url_protocol'] = "AUTO";**

I have tried this in each of the settings and none seem to make it work.

**Code Igniter error logs...**

These are the result of switching '$config['log_threshold'] = 4' within config.php (../admin/system/application/config).

```
ERROR - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Severity: 8192  --> Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated /var/www/html/website/httpdocs/admin/system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php 46
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Helpers loaded: url, form, array, auth
ERROR - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Severity: 8192  --> Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated /var/www/html/website/httpdocs/admin/system/database/DB.php 81
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Session Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Helpers loaded: url
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Helpers loaded: form
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Config file loaded: config/bookings_settings.php
ERROR - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Severity: 8192  --> Function ereg() is deprecated /var/www/html/website/httpdocs/admin/system/libraries/Config.php 177
ERROR - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Severity: 8192  --> Function ereg() is deprecated /var/www/html/website/httpdocs/admin/system/libraries/Config.php 177
ERROR - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Severity: 8192  --> Function ereg() is deprecated /var/www/html/website/httpdocs/admin/system/libraries/Config.php 177 
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> File loaded: /var/www/html/website/httpdocs/admin/system/application/views/login_view.php
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2012-08-27 15:41:41 --> Total execution time: 0.0278
```

There were also repeated warnings regarding an incorrect timezone declaration which PHP states it corrects. I have stripped these out to make the log readable.

The 'deprecated' error messages suggest that my version of PHP is more recent than the version online - but I am assuming that these are just warnings and the functions should still work with the version I am using.

At this stage I am stumped - if you have any idea on what the problem could be, or how I could better approach the troubleshooting please could you take a moment to give me a hand?

Comment: have you tried to run a clean basic version of codeigniter on your test system? see if that even works. all the old versions are available - so you can even confirm the exact same version will run on your machine

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I had installed the latest version of CodeIgniter on this setup to test (just to the initial 'Welcome to CodeIgniter' page). I have just tried the earlier CI version that the site is built using and it generates the Welcome page but includes an error on the page: "Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated. Filename: codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php" - I'm starting to think I might have to get my head around the code to get it working?

Comment: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is an warning message that occurred on some of the older versions of CI on PHP5. You can ignore that (for now). You'll need to try and move parts of the code over slowly and see if you can isolate the issue

Comment: My first gut feeling is it's all about permissions. Make sure that the permissions locally reflect the permissions as they run on the hosted server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your php version is way ahead of the live version. However, it also looks odd. I'm not sure what version of CI had the file "system/libraries/Config.php" tbh, it's probably an very old one.

You have two options here as those errors will cause your db stuff to fail for some things such as your admin login.

Option 1 is to use php 5.1.x as that should work with the code you have i think.
Option 2 is going to involve an update to codeigniter and i'm guessing a fairly large re-write to a lot of your app as if it uses any third party libraries, they will probably not work with the latest codeigniter version.